# c# Interfaces, Dependency Inversion and Generic Types

Tags: c#, interface, dependencies

I've been battling with this for a while. I have an API to retrieve datasources in JSON format:

Datasources:

```
[
 {
        "name": "Datasource 1",
        "tags": "Ds1",
        "product": 1,
        "status": 1,
        "Type": 2,
        "datasource": {
            "testurl1" : "",
            "testurl2: : ""
        }

},
 {
        "name": "Datasource 2",
        "tags": "Ds2",
        "product": 2,
        "status": 1,
        "Type": 2,
        "datasource": {
            "string1" : "",
            "string2: : ""
        }

}
]
```

The datasources have the same outer properties. However, the datasource property will differ. The datasource property will consist of it's own set of properties that are different from datasource to datasource.

I've created an Interface that I want to use across different projects:

```
public Interface IGeneral
{
   void SetTestData(TestDataModel testData);
}
```

but you see the TestDataModel type is a concrete type. I've gone down the road of trying a Strategy Pattern and creating a BaseDatasource class with a generic datasource property, but I'm not sure on the best way forward.

Basically, I want to retrieve a datasource, bind it to the necessary POCO model, instantiate a class the implements the IGeneral interface, and then call the SetTestData method of that class and pass in the datasource object without it being a concrete type. And inside the SetTestData method I would have code similar to this:

Example 1:

```
public class MyClass1 : IGeneral
{
     public void SetTestData(TestDataModel testData)
        {
            testData.product = 1;
            testData.datasource.testurl1 = "sasasas";
        }
}
```

Example 2:

```
public class MyClass2 : IGeneral
{
     public void SetTestData(TestDataModel testData)
        {
            testData.product = 2;
            testData.datasource.string1 = "dsds";
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Have you considered [`dynamic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic) ? I'm not 100% sure if this is a usecase for it, though.

Comment: What's wrong with using `Dictionary<string, object>`?

Answer (score 1):

Does this fit the bill:

```
class DataSourceBase
{
}
class DataSource1 : DataSourceBase
{
}

class TestDataPerMarket<TDataSource> where TDataSource : DataSourceBase
{
    public int product {get;set;}
    public TDataSource datasource {get;set;}
}

public Interface IGeneral
{
    void SetTestData<TDM<TDS>>(TDM<TDS> testData) 
        where TDM : class, 
        where TDS : DataSourceBase;
}
```

(p.s. I've not tried compiling this!)